# showing diffrent div in a main window based on link click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to figure out a way to get a div based on which link a user clicks on the show. 
by default there is text in the main window. When a user clicks on one of the 7 links the associated hidden div would show hiding the default text. then based on which link is clicked it would show the related div and hide the previous one.
What would be a good way to acheive this? Im new to divs and java I dont know how to go about doing this. I know I need css and javascript but every thing I try is not working

this is the hidden divs in the main window.

```
<div id="hiddendiv">
<id="link1">hidden link 1</div>
<id="link2">hidden link 2</div>
<id="link3">hidden link 3</div>
<id="link4">hidden link 4</div>
<id="link5">hidden link 5</div>
<id="link6">hidden link 6</div>
<id="link7">hidden link 7</div>
</div>
```

Here are the links to click on the display the div in the main window.

```
<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link1">link1</a></div>

<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link2">link2</a></div>

<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link3">link3</a></div>

<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link4">link4</a></div>

<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link5">link5</a></div>

<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link6">link6</a></div>

<div id="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link7">link7</a></div>
```

please excuse the crude pic it wont let me upload a pic as a new person. LEts hope the formatting stays the same when I post.
http://oi41.tinypic.com/2ymvps2(dot)jpg
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
+--header---------------------------------------------------+
+--description----------------------------------------------+
+**********************************************************************************************+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link1-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link2-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link3-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link4-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link5-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link6-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||--link7-------+
+---------main window/main window--|||---------------+
+-----------------------------------------------|||---------------+
+-----------------------------------------------|||---------------+
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: `$('div').hide(); $('div#id').show();` Can you show the HTML where the text is that needs to be hidden / shown.

Comment: `id's` are always unique. `carlist1` remove

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it: http://jsfiddle.net/n4hqF/

```
<div class="hiddendiv">
   <div class="hide" id="link1">hidden link 1</div>
   <div class="hide" id="link2">hidden link 2</div>
   <div class="hide" id="link3">hidden link 3</div>
   <div class="hide" id="link4">hidden link 4</div>
   <div class="hide" id="link5">hidden link 5</div>
   <div class="hide" id="link6">hidden link 6</div>
   <div class="hide" id="link7">hidden link 7</div>
</div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link1">link1</a></div>

 <div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link2">link2</a></div>

<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link3">link3</a></div>

<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link4">link4</a></div>

 <div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link5">link5</a></div>

<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link6">link6</a></div>

 <div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link7">link7</a></div>
```

**JS**

I am guessing you already have jquery library

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('.hide').hide();
   $('.carlist1').show();
   var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).closest( "div" ).hide();
   $("#" + rel).show();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
  display:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the div tag name and ids must be unique, use a class instead. There is place for improvement but I kept your markup and made a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ3En/).

The HTML :

```
<div id="hiddendiv">
    <div id="link1">hidden link 1</div>
    <div id="link2">hidden link 2</div>
    <div id="link3">hidden link 3</div>
    <div id="link4">hidden link 4</div>
    <div id="link5">hidden link 5</div>
    <div id="link6">hidden link 6</div>
    <div id="link7">hidden link 7</div>
</div>

<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link1">link1</a></div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link2">link2</a></div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link3">link3</a></div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link4">link4</a></div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link5">link5</a></div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link6">link6</a></div>
<div class="carlist1"><a href="#" rel="link7">link7</a></div>
```

And the Jquery :

```
$( "#hiddendiv div" ).hide(); // hide all the div not supposed to be visible

$( '.carlist1' ).on( 'click', function () {
    var hiddenLinkId = "#" + $( this ).children( "a" ).attr( "rel" ); 

    $( hiddenLinkId ).show(); // this will show the hidden link corresponding to the rel data
    $( this ).hide(); // if you want to hide the clicked link
} );
```